# Swipe on item-list is not working not showing option button for windows phone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing application using ionic on windows phone 8.
First issue that i face was scrolling, i was unable to scroll ion-list. I fixed it by putting overflow-scroll="true" attribute in "ion-content" tag, and list started to scroll. There is ion-list in "ion-content" and each item has option buttons(need to be show on swipe).

By fixing my scrolling issue i am not able to swipe list item. list-item is not swiping.

but when i remove overflow-scroll="true" from "ion-content" tag, then swipe start working for list item but scrolling stop working

I am not facing any difficulty like this in android and ios, in both scroll and swipe is working fine, But not working in windows phone 8.

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" class="has-footer" scroll="true" has-bouncing="false">
        <ion-list class="margin-top-10 list" can-swipe="true">
             <ion-item ng-repeat="os in customerService" item="os" style="margin-top: -5px;">
                <div class="row" style="margin: -18px !important;">
                    <div class="col col-90">
                        <div class="row app-font-size">
                            <div class="col item-text-wrap"><b>{{os.po}}</b></div>
                            <div class="col item-text-wrap"><b>{{os.so}}</b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row app-font-size">
                            <div class="col item-text-wrap"><b>{{os.grade}}</b></div>
                            <div class="col item-text-wrap"><b>{{os.product}}</b></div>
                        </div>
                        <ion-option-button style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;">
                            <i class="ion-at app-icon" style="font-size:40px !important;"></i>
                        </ion-option-button>
                        <ion-option-button style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;">
                            <i class="ion-email app-icon" style="font-size:40px !important;"></i>
                        </ion-option-button>
                        <ion-option-button style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;">
                            <i class="ion-ios7-telephone app-icon" style="font-size:40px !important;"></i>
                        </ion-option-button>
                        <ion-option-button style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;">
                            <i class="ion-pie-graph app-icon" style="font-size:40px !important;"></i>
                        </ion-option-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```